# How to specify both IP address and port in tcpdump?

Tags: tcpdump

I want to specify a source IP address, destination IP address and source port in my tcpdump filter. However, I keep getting syntax errors. How do I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tcpdump filters can be combined with the `and` and `or` keywords. Here is the command that satisfied my filtering requirements:

`tcpdump -i enp1s9 dst 192.168.6.1 and src 192.168.6.2 and src port 80`

Where `enp1s9` is the name of the interface.

Comment: This didn't work for me unless I changed "and src port" to "and port".